# Include And Exclude Tax In Magento2

Tags: magento2

[image]i added tax rule in my store but the issue is my exl price and incl price showing same in magento2.3.3 what is the bug.

£210.00
£210.00 Exlude tax

Comment: Have you applied tax rule for your country ?

Comment: yes pakistan applied